# como puedo hacer un promedio de notas en una matriz de N x 3 en c#

Tags: c#

Tengo un ejercicio que me pide calcular el promedio de las notas de examen de N estudiantes y trate de solucionarlo con siclos for. Pero al ejecutarlo no me muestra los resultados y quisiera saber como arrglarlo para que funcione a la perfección.

Quisiera saber como solucionar este ejercicio, ya que al principio tenía dudas y me decidí hacerlo con la suma de filas y de columnas, pero creo que cometí un error, pero por falta de experiencia no logro ver cuál es el problema

no soy muy experimentado y talvez el código tiene un problema de lógica, pero no logro visualizarlo y agradecería la ayuda y de ante mano gracias

este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Realice_un_programa_que_imprima_el_promedio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Pedir(string m,ref int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
            x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        static void Llenar(int[,] ma, int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("De el dato: ");
                    ma[i, j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("\t");
                }
        }

        static void Oper(int[,] ma, int n)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
               int sum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    sum = sum + ma[i, j];
                }
                Console.WriteLine("La suma del estudiante ", i + 1, "es",sum);
                Console.WriteLine("\n");

            }

            Console.WriteLine("<<< El promedio de los examenes es >>>");
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
               int sum = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    sum = sum + ma[i, j];
                }
               double prom = sum / 3;
                Console.WriteLine("La suma de los examenes del estudiante ", j + 1, "es", sum);
                Console.WriteLine("El promedio es: ",prom);
            }
        }

        static void Imp(int[,] ma, int n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n\n<<< Imprimiendo Los Datos Del Arreglo >>>\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < ma.Length; i++)
                for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                Console.Write("[{0}]", ma[i,j]);
                }
        }
        
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = 0;
            Pedir("Cuantos alumnos quiere: ", ref n);
            int[,] ma = new int[n,3];
            Llenar(ma, n);
            Oper(ma, n);
            Imp(ma, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cúal es el error?

Comment: el error es que ya ejecutado no me muestra los resultados de las operaciones

Comment: Los errores que logro ver es que estas utilizando mal   "Console.WriteLine("La suma del estudiante ", i + 1, "es",sum);" deberia ser "Console.WriteLine("La suma del estudiante {0} {1} {2}", i + 1, "es", sum);" tambien en el codigo de imprimir "(int i = 0; i < ma.Length; i++)"  creo que deberia ser i<n en vez de ma.Length.